# How to store and format a quantity of days/weeks/months in Swift?

Tags: swift

I would like to create not `Date` but simple quantities of time (i.e. durations) whose units are either days, weeks or months, then format them nicely as "1 day", "7 days", "3 weeks", "1 month", etc.

However both `Duration` and `Measurement<UnitDuration>` initializers do not accept these units.

```
// Type 'Duration' has no member 'days'
let duration: Duration = .days(7)
```

```
// Type 'UnitDuration' has no member 'days'
let measurement: Measurement<UnitDuration> = .init(value: 7, unit: .days)
```

I tried to extend `UnitDuration` but it does not allow to automatically format units to plural.

```
extension UnitDuration {
    static let days = UnitDuration(
        symbol: "days",
        converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 60 * 60 * 24)
    )
}

let measurement: Measurement<UnitDuration> = .init(value: 1, unit: .days)
measurement.formatted(.measurement(width: .wide, usage: .asProvided)) // "1 days" :(
```

The aim is to get something like this :

```
let onDay: Duration = .days(1)
let eightWeeks: Duration = .weeks(8)
oneDay.formatted() // "1 day"
eightWeeks.formatted() // "8 weeks"
```

Comment: You could either: (1) Store the number of seconds, then convert them to hours, days, etc. (2) Or, you could use timestamp, as many databases use, which can be converted into hours, days, and such.

Comment: I think the closest thing would be `DateComponents` together with `DateComponentsFormatter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Fabio says, you could use a `DateComponentsFormatter`:

```
formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
formatter.allowedUnits = [.weekOfMonth]

let components = DateComponents(weekOfMonth: 13)

if let string = formatter.string(from: components) {
    print(string)
} else {
    print("Unable to convert components to a String")
}
```

That code outputs "13 weeks" as expected.

### Edit:

You can also request multiple different units, e.g. weeks, days, hours, and minutes, and the `DateComponentsFormatter` will compose a description of the time interval using multiple units. Example:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]

let components = DateComponents(day: 2, hour: 3, weekOfMonth: 54 )

if let string = formatter.string(from: components) {
    print(string)
} else {
    print("Unable to convert components to a String")
}
```

That outputs "54 weeks, 2 days, 3 hours".

`DateComponentsFormatter` also has a `func string(from: TimeInterval)` function that will take an arbitrary number of seconds and express it in terms of the units you ask for.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this using the new `formatted()` function introduced in iOS 15?

Comment: @alobaili, in a word, no. the formatted() function uses default output styles for the types it supports. `DateComponents` doesn't implement a `formatted()` function, so you'd have to create a Date from your desired components, and then you wouldn't have any control over which units were used.